# Return a default image, if no image is found Laravel Intervention

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5.4, intervention

For a travel application, the mobile application needs to get a default image for each city from their city code.

For example: example.com/imageCache/thumbnail/JFK.png

Where thumbnail is custom filter defined as:

```
/**
 * Sample filter for image manipulation
 * via image cache
 */

namespace App\ImageFilters;


use Intervention\Image\Filters\FilterInterface;
use Intervention\Image\Image;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic;

class Thumbnail implements FilterInterface
{

    /**
     * Applies filter to given image
     *
     * @param  Image $image
     * @return Image
     */
    public function applyFilter(Image $image)
    {
        //TODO: Do something to check if the image doesn't exist.

        $gradient = ImageManagerStatic::make(public_path('images/gradient.png'));
        return $image->fit(200, 200)->insert($gradient,'center')->blur();
    }
}
```

The application however throws 404 even before this function is called.

I would like to show a default image, if the image is not found.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think thre is a problem in you routes !

Comment: Can we see the make command?

Comment: It works for images that exist. Just when the image doesn't exist it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The URL manipulation as it is may not work in this case.

Write a route `getCityImage/{cityCode}` as:

```
public function getCityImage($cityCode){

     if(file_exists('path_to_city_images/'.$cityCode.'.png'){
        $image = Intervention\Image\Image::make('path_to_city_images/'.$cityCode.'.png');
        return $image->filter(new Thumbnail());
      }
       else {
        return $your_default_image;
      }

}
```